# Find script that is setting a third-party cookie?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking at [this website](http://national-lottery.co.uk). In Chrome's developer tools, I can see that it's setting third-party cookies from doubleclick.net, including DSID and IDE.

Is there any way to see which script is setting those cookies, short of unminifying all the site's JS?

I'm confused because these are [Google advertising cookies](https://business.safety.google/adscookies/), but the site doesn't seem to be displaying Google ads, so I'm curious about where they are being set.

Comment: These cookies are set by the server via `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: Thank you! How do you know that? Just inspected the page headers in the Network tab, and I can see a bunch of `Set-Cookie` headers, but not of the kind that I can tie to any one of those cookies.

Comment: Also, if I do `curl -c cookies.txt https://www.national-lottery.co.uk` I don't actually see those cookies.

Comment: Sorry, I have misread the names. The cookies you're looking for aren't present when I open the site. Maybe they are leftovers from an old version of the site that you have opened previously.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm - I have to disable my ad blocker and click 'accept all cookies', then wait a minute or two, to see them. But I do see them.

Comment: Further debugging: hm, I see them in some browsers and not others. I see them in my main Chrome browser, but not in a vanilla (non-incognito) Chrome install on a different user account. What could that be about? Could being logged into Google in the browser make a difference?